# String formatting in Perl

Tags: string, perl

I have a string whose middle part will be changed based on a condition. 
Something like this:

```
"You have x number of problems";
```

The value of x has different text based on some if conditions.
One way I could do is to store "You have" in one variable and "number of problems" in another variable and
do something like `sprintf("%s%d%s", $firstpart, $x, $secondpart);`

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, strings are constructed in Perl using [interpolation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary.html#interpolation): put the variable right in the string.

```
my $numProblems = 99;
my $text = "You got $numProblems problems, but Perl ain't one.";
```

This only works on simple variables, and things like array and hash access. Expressions and method calls don't work.

```
# Accessing a hash or array works.
my $text = "You got $numProblems{$user} problems, but Perl ain't one.";

# Method call does not work.
my $text = "You got $user->numProblems problems, but Perl ain't one.";
```

You can use the [baby-cart "secret operator"](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlsecret#Baby-cart) to fool Perl into interpolating expressions.

```
my $text = "You got @{[$user->numProblems]} problems, but Perl ain't one.";
```

You can read about all the [Gory Details Of Interpolation in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Gory-details-of-parsing-quoted-constructs).

---

You can also use `sprintf`, but generally that's only when you need to do formatting. There's no need for separate variables for the start and end of the string.

```
my $text = sprintf "You got %d problems, but Perl ain't one.", $numProblems;
```

Comment: Looks like the variable $numProblems has to be set before $text. The value of $numProblems is set for me later on in if conditions after some calculations.

Comment: @user1692342 Yes, strings are interpolated immediately and work exactly like string concatenation. `$text = "This $var that"` is literally syntax sugar for `$text = 'this '.$var.' that'`. If the message is a user defined template, make it a format string for `sprintf`. If it's a hard coded message, move the creation of `$text` after the calculation of `$numProblems`. Generally you do the calculations, then format the output.

Comment: Perhaps throw in a blurb on using braces if the var you're interpolating rests against a word char that would make the var invalid? eg: `print "This is ${name}'s stuff\n";`

Comment: @stevieb Rather than try to cover every special case, I've linked to the detailed docs about interpolation. If there's a more user friendly doc, please LMK.